# BehaviorSubject doesn't immediately change value

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, guard

I am creating a custom login service with `AuthGuard` from `Angular`. I have a `SessionService` which have methods such a `login()` or `onUserLoggedIn()` which basically returns `BehaviorSubject` with the current value of user status (logged in/not logged in). Based on this service I created an implementation of `AuthGuard implements CanActivate` service. I call `onUserLoggedIn` method and check the current value in subject. The problem here is that in `login` method value is changed after the `AuthGuard` call `onUserLoggedIn`. Therefore in a first attempt I receive false value from BehaviorSubject but when I try the second time, I received a true value.

How can I change the implementation of those two services to achieve current value in a first attempt?

AuthGuard:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)
    : Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    console.log('auth');

    return this.sessionService.onUserLoggedIn()
      .pipe(
        map(res => {
          console.log('res', res);
          return res;
        }),
        take(1),
        tap(allowed => {
          console.log(allowed);
          if (!allowed) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          }
        })
      );
  }
```

SessionService:

```
private isLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
  }

  login(user: User): Observable<any> {
    console.log('hello before');
    return this.apiService.post(`${BASE_URL}/login`, user)
      .pipe(
        tap((token: Token) => {
          this.isLoggedIn.next(true);
          localStorage.setItem('token', token.token);
          console.log('hello');
        })
      );
  }

  onUserLoggedIn() {
    return this.isLoggedIn;
  }
```

First attempt goes with printing value:

- SessionService.ts:19 hello before
- AuthGuard.ts:17 auth
- AuthGuard.ts:22 res false
- AuthGuard.ts:27 false
- SessionService.ts:25 hello

The second one (which I expect to be first):

- SessionService.ts:19 hello before
- AuthGuard.ts:17 auth
- AuthGuard.ts:22 res true
- AuthGuard.ts:27 true
- SessionService.ts:25 hello

Comment: When does your login component redirect?

Answer (score 1):

The nature of BehaviorSubject is, it emit the given value immediately whenever you subscribe.

So based on your use case use Subject. Also use skip operator to skip the first value.

```
return this.sessionService.onUserLoggedIn()
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        map(res => {
          console.log('res', res);
          return res;
        }),
        tap(allowed => {
          console.log(allowed);
          if (!allowed) {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          }
        })
      );
  }
```

use `startsWith(false)` in other components.

Comment: I have to have BehaviorSubject because in other components I need to have default any value

Comment: Any what is the necessity of having the default value here. If you really want false as the default value then use startsWith(false) in other components

Comment: ex. what I display in header (like tabs) are done for a defualt value. But anyway..this is not a goal of that question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try returning it asObservable?

```
onUserLoggedIn() {
        return this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();
      }
```

Comment: piping it automatically returns is asObservable. As long as there is a BehaviorSubject behind the observable, the current value will be returned